# AND Logic Gate Error!

Tags: voltage, led, digital-logic, switches, logic-gates

[image: My AND logic gate]

Hi everyone, 
as you can see from the picture, i have an AND logic gate. The LED has to be off when the Va is 0V and the Vb is 5V, but it turned on?????? Can you guys explain why?

Thank you.

Comment: 0V means, you have connected the Va terminal to GND. Or you left it floating?

Comment: Is R2 actually 10 kohms or 1 kohms like you said in your deleted "answer"?

Comment: Do you have to use that configuration? Exactly that one? Or what flexibility for designing an AND gate do you have? Two transistors, but can they be PNP, for example?

Comment: What are you allowed to do, then? It's a positively crappy topology never found in practice. It has serious problems. Can you move the LED? Can you change resistor values? If you have ZERO latitude, then is the teacher asking you to explain the bad behavior? What exactly is the question? Do you want a fix or an explanation?

Comment: Well, the simple answer has already been given to you. The LED and resistor should be in the collector leg and the emitter should be grounded, if you want it to "operate" better in the case you mentioned. I suppose you don't need to know why, then.

Comment: So the problem is where the LED is at. But it's still a bad design. No need to get into details, I suppose.

Comment: Do not vandalise your own question, by doing so, you invalidate the answers people already posted

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the LED to light dimly with 5V applied to Vb and nothing to Va.

The current will flow through R2 into the base of T2 and then to the LED.

Why do you have the LED and R4 in the emitter of the transistor?

They should be in the collector - the circuit will then work as a AND gate.

It should be similar to below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPNmF7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @BetülYıldırım, With an OR gate, the LED isn't supposed to be off if only one input is high.

Comment: With the OR gate experiment the problem would be masked since the LED should be on whenever there is a voltage applied to Va or Vb and so would hide the fact that the base current is flowing through the LED.  This is not the case with the AND.

Comment: @BetülYıldırım, the real problem with taking the output from the emitter is that your logic is not regenerative. If you cascade multiple gates, the output of each one is lower than the output of the previous stage.